# Repeat Functionality in Alarm

Tags: ios, nsdate, uilocalnotification

I am new to iOS. I am making an alarm application and I want to implement the repeat functionality. I search a lot and didn't understand much how to do this. I know it is done by notification method. I am stuck with it . Please anyone tell me the solution. Here is my  code when user save the alarm.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
NSLog(@"dateformater %@",dateFormatter);
dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle;
NSString * dateTimeString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:timePicker.date];
NSLog(@"date time string %@",dateTimeString);

[dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:NSLocaleIdentifier]];
//[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
datesArray = @[[dateFormatter stringFromDate:self.timePicker.date]];
NSLog(@"dates array is %@",datesArray);

[datesArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)
{
    NSArray * repeatDays = [repeatResult componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    for (NSString * days in repeatDays)
    {
        if ([days isEqualToString:@"Sun"])
        {
            [self getDateOfSpecificDay:1];

        }
        if ([days isEqualToString:@"Mon"])
        {
            [self getDateOfSpecificDay:2];

        }
        if ([days isEqualToString:@"Tue"])
        {
            [self getDateOfSpecificDay:3];

        }
        if ([days isEqualToString:@"Wed"])
        {
            [self getDateOfSpecificDay:4];

        }
        if ([days isEqualToString:@"Thu"])
        {
            [self getDateOfSpecificDay:5];

        }
        if ([days isEqualToString:@"Fri"])
        {
            [self getDateOfSpecificDay:6];

        }
        if ([days isEqualToString:@"Sat"])
        {
            [self getDateOfSpecificDay:7];

        }



    }





}];

AlarmObject * alarm = [[AlarmObject alloc] init];
alarm.repeatData = repeatResult;
alarm.clockDate = dateTimeString;

[self.delegate alarmSetting:alarm];
[self scheduleLocalNotificationWithDate:timePicker.date];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

and here is my `scheduledLocalNotification` mehtod

```
-(void) scheduleLocalNotificationWithDate:(NSDate *)fireDate
{   

 UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
 localNotif.alertBody = @"Time to wake Up";
 localNotif.alertAction = @"Show me";
 localNotif.soundName = @"Tick-tock-sound.mp3";
 localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
 localNotif.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear;
NSLog(@"%@",[NSDate date]);
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];`
```

I'm stuck with it from past 4 days. I know my question is duplicate but I am not sure how implement that logic. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the

```
dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
```

to

```
dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
```

and check out [this](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/repeating-an-ios-local-notification/) tutorial for repeat fucntionailty.